# How to run knockoutjs locally?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to get knockoutjs on my machine but I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. What do I do with the knockout-3.3.0.js file that is given on the download? Please take me step by step on how to execute say http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections tutorial on my machine? Thanks

Comment: if you try to run knockoutjs locally via chrome, then in that case it will not. You will need a local server to run it. But in Firefox, it will run locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make an empty html5 document
- include in its body tag the upper right box's content of the exercise you linked
- before the end body tag include a script element with the src attribute pointing to the knockout library
- after the previous script element, make a new script, and include the lower right box's content in it
- make the adjustments in the html/view content detailed in the upper left box
- load it up in a browser

These steps should be intuitively clear if you've been doing any html/js development.